what is the difference between idealWidth and minWidth in frames - swiftUI
Could I please know the difference between idealWidth and minWidth in frames.
also could anyone give a realtime scenario when to use each.

idealWidth is a suggestion for the view's size, while minWidth is a hard lower bound.
idealWidth: The view will try to match this size, but it can be larger or smaller based on available space.
minWidth: The view will never be smaller than this size, regardless of available space.
Real-world example:
idealWidth: A text view with an ideal width based on its content. It will look best at that size, but it can shrink or grow depending on layout constraints.
minWidth: A button with a minimum width to ensure it's always tappable, even on small screens.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
